# jquery ajax request to gitlab api fails with code 401

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, gitlab

i want to connect with the gitlab api to get some recent commits. it works in curl but the ajax call fails.

i get a status code 401 from the server:

```
{"message":"401 Unauthorized"}
```

the private-token in the header seems right so i have no idea what the problem might be. thanks for the help!

```
:authority: gitlab.example.de (changed to example domain)
:method: GET
:path: /api/v4/projects/83/repository/commits
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
content-type: json
origin: http://labtime.local
pragma: no-cache
private-token: [my token]
referer: http://labtime.local/?
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/65.0.3325.181 Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
```

request code:

```
 $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function(request) {
           request.setRequestHeader("PRIVATE-TOKEN", "[my token]");
      },
      contentType: "json",
      accept:"*/*",
      method:"GET",url:"https://gitlab.example.de/api/v4/projects/"+id+"/repository/commits",
      success: function(data) {
           panel.html(data);
      }
 })
```

Comment: Where are you passing the token in the request?

Comment: hi, i'll put it into the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider trying this

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": https://gitlab.example.de/api/v4/projects/"+id+"/repository/commits,
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "PRIVATE-TOKEN": "TOKEN"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

**NOTE**: Just verify once if you are getting the correct value in URL.I have tested it for users and it is working fine for me.